# How are functions within functions handled?

Tags: python, lambda, test-environments

I'm trying to understand how Python processes the code in the examples below:

When `cake()()` is executed, Python first prints 'beets' then prints 'sweets'

However, when `chocolate()` is executed, Python only prints 'sweets'

Could someone explain the difference for the 2 scenarios?

Also when `more_chocolate` is executed, Python does not print any values, it simply returns 'cake'.

I'm sure there's a tidy explanation for these cases. Hope someone can explain!

```
def cake():
    print('beets')
    def pie():
        print('sweets')
        return 'cake'
    return pie

chocolate = cake()

cake()()

chocolate()

more_chocolate, more_cake = chocolate(), cake

more_chocolate
```

Comment: after `chocolate = cake()` (which also prints `beets`) you have `chocolate =  pie`  so when you use `chocolate()` then you runs `pie()` which can print only `sweets`

Comment: what is the meaning of extra indentation between `print('beets')` and `def pie()`? it would produce a syntax error as it's written currently

Comment: `cake()()` works like two other lines `chocolate = cake()` and `chocolate()`

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
chocolate = cake()
```

This binds the identifier `chocolate` to the object returned by invoking `cake` - it returns a function object - therefore, chocolate is bound to that function object (`chocolate` is bound to the function object `pie`).
A side effect of invoking `cake` is is that "beets" is printed.

```
cake()()
```

This invokes `cake`, which returns a function object. This time the function object is not bound to a name. Upon returning we invoke the anonymous function object. The result is "beets" is printed from the call to `cake`, and "sweets" is printed from the call to `pie`. `pie` also returns the string "cake", but that string is not bound or captured.

```
chocolate()
```

`chocolate` is still bound to the function object returned by `cake` when we did `chocolate = cake()`. Now we are simply invoking the function object we captured earlier. Since we are not actually calling `cake` now (we're only calling `pie`), "beets" is not printed, but "sweets" is. Again, this returns the string "cake", but again, it is not bound or captured.

```
more_chocolate, more_cake = chocolate(), cake
```

this binds `more_chocolate` to the object returned by calling `chocolate` (which is the string "cake"). It also binds `more_cake` to `cake`. Not sure if you actually meant to do this - all this does is it binds `more_cake` to the same function object that `cake` is bound to, but you're not actually invoking any function here.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `cake()`, the following chunk is run:

```
print('beets')
def pie():
    print('sweets')
    return 'cake'
return pie
```

So it:

- prints `beets`
- executes the `pie` function definition, the function body is not run yet hence no printing of `sweets`
- returns the `pie` function object

You're saving the returned function object as name `chocolate`, so it now refers to the `pie` function object.

So when you execute `chocolate()`, it actually runs `pie()` now and does the following:

- prints `sweets`
- returns string `cake`

---

When you do `cake()()` it also does the same thing without using the intermediate variable `chocolate`. So `cake()()` runs the returned function object from `cake()` i.e. `pie` with the prints.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called [Currying Function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/currying-function-in-python/). In functional programming, currying is the way to simplify multiple arguments function into a simpler function with a single argument.

To understand the behavior of your example lets break it down:

```
def cake():
    print('beets')
    def pie():
        print('sweets')
        return 'cake'
    return pie
```

Here we have a function cake which is going to print **beets** and return a function pie.

Now if we invoke it using:

```
cake()()
```

Here we invoked it twice, first when `cake()` will be executed it will print **beets** and return *pie function* which immediately going to get invoked due to the second set of *()* results printing **sweets**

While if we execute it:

```
chocolate = cake()
```

We executed only one time so it will print **beets** and returning pie function will be set into the variable *chocolate*.

and later when we invoke chocolate it will print **sweets** also it returns a string **cake**. Which you in later case save in *more_chocolate* variable. Since it is just a string literal and not printing anything that's the reason nothing get printed on the output.